# What happens to the Syamantaka Jewel(श्यामन्तक मणि) after Krishna leaves the material world?

Tags: krishna, vishnu-purana

The story about Syamantaka mani is well discribed in the Vishnu Purana and the Bhagavata.

Is there anything mentioned in Puranas about what happens to the gem after Krishna leaves the material world ?